# How to turn "array-like" string into array

Tags: php, arrays

My site is giving me a string that looks like this:

```php
a:2:{i:0;s:4:"3042";i:1;s:4:"3044";}
```

Each number between the quotes is the ID of an image, so I need to turn the above into a PHP array, something like:

```php
Array
(
    [1] => 3042
    [2] => 3044
)
```

I tried:

```php
$var = str_replace(array('";'), ',', $var);

$var = preg_replace("/[^0-9\,]/", "",$var);

$var = explode(',',$var);
```

However, that gets me an array with a couple of unwanted numbers in it:

```php
Array
(
    [1] => 243042
    [2] => 143044
)
```

Of course, this is because the preg_replace can't tell which numbers to strip out and which to leave.

I'm stumped... There must be an easier way to do this?

Comment: It's serialized data. Do what wrightee said in his answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
unserialize('a:2:{i:0;s:4:"3042";i:1;s:4:"3044";}');
```